# Prove that $\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}\mathrm dx \in [2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}\mathrm dx \in [2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$

I can't calculate this. From Wolfram I know that: $$\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}\mathrm dx= \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{\text{erfi}}{2}+\frac{3 \text{erfi}}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt[4]{e}}$$ so it doesn’t seem to be expressable with elementary functions. I thus think that I have to estimate the integral.

However I don't have an idea which derivatives can be helpful for me. I thought about:
$$e^{-x}\le e^{x^2-x}\le e^{x^2}$$ So: $$\int e^{-x}\le \int e^{x^2-x}\le \int e^{x^2}$$However, this is not helpful for me since the interval $[2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$ is more precise.

Have you got some idea how to find adequate functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On $[0,\,2]$, $x^2-x=\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac14$ has minimum $\frac14$ at $x=\frac12$, maximum $2$ at $x=2$. So your integrand is bound between $e^{-\frac14},\,e^2$. Now just multiply by the integration range's width $2$.